# Check similar expressions using ANTLR

Tags: java, data-structures, antlr

I'm new to using **ANTLR** and I was wondering if there is a way to check similar expressions.  For example, how could I validate two expressions that are logically equivalent, such as the following

```
(a+b) <=> (b+a) ; 
(a+(b+c)) <=> ((a+b)+c) ; 
(a && b) <=> (b && a) ; 
(a < b) <==> (b > a) ; etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is an algebra question.  Although your examples are simple, I assume you also mean things like:

```
   a^2-a+3 <==> a*(a-1)+b*3/b
```

To do the algebra, you need to parse the expressions into some internal form, and then ask if they can be transformed by applying algebraic rules into equivalent forms.  For instance, one of your equivalences is determined by a distributive law.

ANTLR is a parsing engine.  It reads syntax you define, and maybe it builds ASTs if you so direct it.  But it doesn't rewrite the trees after they are parsed, and has no way to even express that.  (ANTLR has some peculiar *unrelated* terminology about "rewriting", but I think that applies only during the *construction* of an individual tree).

For that you need something more like a program transformation system, which parses, builds trees, and then can apply "term" rewriting rules to transform the trees into other trees.
You also need a way to express the rules that are allowed.  Given such rules, the system then needs to figure out a sequence of rewrites that will convert one "term" (tree) into another. (A common trick is to apply normalizing transformations; if two formulas normalize to the same result, then they are equal).

This is exactly how Mathematica works, but Mathematica is generally limited to more mathematic things such as pure algebra. (You can abuse it into doing other things, but mostly that's just abusive).

For your example, you need rules about boolean operations (&&, ||) and about some kind of algebra with arithmetic with operators (+, >, ...)

This is a *lot* more than ANTLR supplies, or can be easily built with ANTLR (or any other "just" parser generator because... well, they are just parser generators). (What you reasonably can do with ANTLR is to build two trees and them compare them to see if they have exactly the same structure).

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit can do this.  Normally we apply it to transforming complex source codes to "improve" them in some way.   Often it turns out this improvement requires reasoning about boolean and algbraic formulas, e.g., whether one formula is equivalent to true or false.   (Example: If you can show that a condition in an IF statement is FALSE, you can delete the IF statement from the program).

Here I [describe how DMS can do Boolean algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039406/120163) by defining a grammar for boolean algebra, and writing
explicit rewrite rules.

Here I show how [DMS can do reasoning about algebra involving numbers](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html).  This follows the same paradigm: a grammar for the algebra, and again, a set of rewrite rules.

One could easily put them together, to handle the kinds of expressions you find in computer programs.  (We often do exactly that... actually, we define a grammar for a computer lanuage and just pick up the expression part).

Using this kind of machinery, one can pick out formulas in the program, and manipulate/compare them for certain kinds of equality.   To do this really well, you need a theory guiding the rewrites, often called a "decision procedure".  DMS does not contain decision procedures at present.

You also have to handle associative and commutative laws.  These turn out to be very hard to do with pure rewrite rules; you need special support for these algebraic properties.  These are built into DMS.

Comment: Thanks @Ira Baxter, for your valuable reply. But I'm getting confused between ANTLR and DMS. What I've understood that ANTLR parses your expression into tree by reading grammar and same it is happening with DMS. As you said "(What you reasonably can do with ANTLR is to build two trees and them compare them to see if they have exactly the same structure)." Is DMS capable of generating same tree structure of expressions that are logically equivalent? If yes then it means DMS already have pre-defined grammars written for expressing same tree structures.

Comment: Yes, both ANTLR and DMS accept grammars, and both build parsers, and the parsers built by both will read a formula according to the grammar and build a corresponding tree.  ANTLR stops there; you can build some custom code on top of ANTLR to make it read two formulas, and compare the trees.  At that point, ANTLR is pushed more or less as far as you can push it for this task without a huge amount of additional work.  You could build conceptually similar code on top of DMS for the same effect.  So far, no useful difference...

Comment: ... The point is that DMS can go much further, out of the box; you can specify rich rewrite rules, including automatic management of associative and distributive laws, and have DMS apply them for you, and have DMS even print the results of that application.  If you look at the algebra example, you can see exactly what you have to say to DMS to get it to process equations algebraically.  (All the tree building gook happens for free behind the scenes).  Neither DMS or ANTLR have "gramamrs" to express tree structures; they accept grammars that controls how they build corresponding tree strutures.